# Post data to html page and display page in div

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

Below is the `html form` with post data for url and open the page.

```html
<form id="payment" name="payment" method="POST" action="https://url-xxx/payMe.aspx">
    <input name="param1" type="hidden" value="VDJ98">
    <input name="param2" type="hidden" value="ANQN2080">
    <input name="param3" type="hidden" value="56GHJ345">
    <input name="param4" type="hidden" value="ESCENTER">
    <input name="param5" type="hidden" value="100">
</form>
```

I want to replicate this in `Angular2`
i.e. On a click of a button on a component I want to post data and open a external page (**payment gateway page**).

```js
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

const TAG:string = "TESTING : ";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-testing',
    templateUrl: './testing.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./testing.component.scss']
})

export class TestingComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.openExpernalPage();
    }

    private openExpernalPage(){
        /**
          * I want to open this external-url
          * pass data
          * param1 : 123123123
          * param2: sdfsdf34534
          * param3:amit787
        */
        window.location.href = 'http://external-url';
    }
}
```

All in Breif:

1. I have a payment gateway post url and some params to be passed.
2. I execute that url by using HTTP and on success it returns HTML Page.
3. This html page is a payment page.

Ques: How to show this payment page to user ?

Comment: Why don't you just place this form in your html template?

Comment: @MaciejSobala can you please brief me about using html template and post and suitable example link.